# IP Forwarding not working in VirtualBox VM

Tags: virtualbox, routing

I am trying to set up a networking testbed locally using VirtualBox. I have two VMs. One VM (A) has two interfaces, eth0 and eth1, and the other machine (B) only has one, eth0. They are set up as follows.

```
eth0 on A is connected to NAT network: 172.31.0.0/16 and has IP 172.31.0.2
eth1 on A is connected to NAT network: 10.0.0.0/8 and has IP 10.0.0.2

eth0 on B is connected to NAT network: 172.31.0.0/16 and has IP 172.31.0.3
```

The routing table on A looks like this:

```
default via 10.0.0.1 dev eth1 proto static
172.31.0.0/16 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 172.31.0.2
10.0.0.0/8 dev eth1 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.0.2
```

I can send traffic directly from B to A across the 172.31.0.0/16 network.

I wish to be able to forward packets from eth0 to eth1 on A. I add the following route on B:

`ip route add 10.0.0.0/8 via 172.31.0.2`

On A, I set the following parameters using sysctl:

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
net.conf.ipv4.all.rp_filter=0
```

So I try to ping 10.0.0.1 (the gateway for the 10/8 network) from B. The packet reaches A, which I can confirm with tcpdump, however after that it just seems to disappear. It doesn't get forwarded through the other interface, and doesn't even seem to hit any chains on iptables at all (I've tried logging them all).

I have recreated a similar setup on AWS, and it works as expected. Can anyone suggest what might be happening, or how I could go about diagnosing this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to some suggestions I received on the virtual box forums, I discovered that this issue is due to a limitation of the NAT Networking mode in virtual box.

The implementation of NAT Networks does not accurately simulate real networks. Instead the virtual box host application seems to intercept outbound packets from the guest network interface that do not have a destination address within the NAT Network subnet.

This means that you can't really achieve my desired scenario above using NAT Networks in virtual box.

Comment: I do not think this is true.  I got a similar setup working for a few years.  I recently broke it when updating the virtual network topology and it took me a few hours to find that I forgot to setup MASQUERADE NAT on my new WAN interface.